# Can not include iostream in Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I try to use `cpp` file with android project. I can use c functions without error. I add `Core.cpp` and `Core.h` in jni folder. After I only add `#include <iostream>` and android studio gives `iostream: No such file or directory` error. I have `Application.mk` with this line `APP_STL:=stlport_stati`c . How can I use cpp files in Android Studio ?

I am using `Android Studio 1.5.1` on `Xubuntu 14.04`

---

I have no `Android.mk` and my `build.gradle` file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = '23.0.0'
        compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251' // write your encoding here

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.example.example"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 19
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 21
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
        }
    }

    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "hello-jni"
    }

    android.productFlavors {
        // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
        // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
        create("arm") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
        }
        create("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
        }
        create("arm8") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
        }
        create("x86") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86")
        }
        create("x86-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86_64")
        }
        create("mips") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("mips")
        }
        create("mips-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("mips64")
        }
        // To include all cpu architectures, leaves abiFilters empty
        create("all")
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.51.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Please include your build.gradle and Android.mk (if you use it).

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your build.gradle to specify what C++ library to link to.

```
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "hello-jni"
    stl        = "stlport_static"
}
```

See some examples of build.gradle files using the experimental NDK support [here (hello-thirdparty)](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/229cbe86238d401bb06166b8dfadec8198532589/hello-thirdparty/app/build.gradle) and [here (endless-tunnel)](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/0f60ab4b8567a895f80de047f2819fc386e2fd80/endless-tunnel/app/build.gradle).