# Compiling .cpp file for android in windows

Tags: android, c++

I have a cpp file named main.cpp written in codeblocks. I want to compile it for android in windows 10 64bit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> 
using namespace std;



#define greater(x,y) (x<y?y:x);

int main(){


int a,b;
cout<<"Enter two numbers "<<endl;
cin>>a>>b;
cout<< "The greater number is "<<greater(a,b);

}
```

I use android ndk toolchain for windows . I opened the cmd and used this command .

```
x86_64-linux-android-gcc.exe main.cpp -o main.
```

The error I am facing ..

```
 fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
  #include <iostream>
                ^
compilation terminated.
```

I think I have done the wrong procedure .

EDIT:
I found my answer.

Source :http://tricksfairbd.blogspot.com/2018/05/compile-cpp-code-for-android-in-windows.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory in compiling C program using GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543286/fatal-error-iostream-no-such-file-or-directory-in-compiling-c-program-using-gc)

Comment: Did my answer clarify for you? If so, would you be able to mark it as the "accepted answer" by clicking on the green checkmark by the answer?

Comment: Ok but my question was a bit different. There was no use of android studio. Direct toolchain. I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell `gradle` to include the requisite libraries so that it can be compiled with them.

In `build.gradle`, you should include something similar to the following:

```
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "hello-jni"
    stl        = "stlport_static"
}
```

Source: [Can not include iostream in Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36283971/can-not-include-iostream-in-android-ndk)